# How to create a bootstrap popover within a bootstrap dropdown?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I created this so far using html, bootstrap, and jQuery v1.12.0, and jQuery UI - v1.10. So far what displays is a button that says "menu". Once you click that button, menu will drop down and display a right-aligned box that says "Popover with data-trigger". Once that happens, I want to be able to click the "Popover with data-trigger" button to popover something using bootstrap. I tried using the onclick stuff, as shown in jquery, but it isn't working. What am I doing wrong?

```js
$(".dropdown-menu").css('margin','50px');
$(function () {
  $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover()
})
$("#popoverData").popover({ trigger: "hover" });
```

```html
<div class="btn-group" style ="left:1860px;top:-140px;">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
    Menu
  </button>
  <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" style="background: rgba(0,0,255,.35);">
    <a id="popoverData" class="btn" href="#" data-content="Popover with data-trigger" rel="popover" data-placement="bottom" data-original-title="Title" data-trigger="hover">Popover with data-trigger</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, I figured out the answer...The thing is I had the right code...
I forgot to put $(document).ready(function() {}); surrounding my popover code, so the code wouldn't run. I think this has something to do with the DOM not being ready? Correct me if I'm wrong guys. This code should work for jquery.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".dropdown-menu").css('margin','50px');
    $(function () {
        $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover()
    })
    $("#popoverData").popover({ trigger: "hover" });
});
```